# отрефакторить код

Tags: java, android, http

Помогите улучшить код

```
public class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String nationality;
    private String state;
    private String city;
    private String street;

    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }
    public String getPhone(){
        return phone;
    }
    public String getNationality(){
        return nationality;
    }
    public String getState(){
        return state;
    }
    public String getCity(){
        return city;
    }
    public String getStreet(){
        return street;
    }

    public User (String firstName,
                 String lastName,
                 String email,
                 String phone,
                 String nationality,
                 String state,
                 String city,
                 String street){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.nationality = nationality;
        this.state = state;
        this.city = city;
        this.street = street;
    }
}
```

Класс Logger - инкапсулирует сообщения об ошибках

```
public class Logger {
    public void logJsonChanged(){
        System.out.println("Не получилось обработать узел json дерева. Структура 
           json у randomuser.me изменилась или другая причина");
    }
}
```

Класс HttpClient - занимается получением ответа по HTTP запросу

```
public class HttpClient {

    private final String url = "https://randomuser.me/api/";

    public StringBuffer getResponseByRequest() {
        try {
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            return response;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Что меня смущает:
- его название
- возможно он слишком короткий и метод getResponseByRequest надо включить в другой класс. Хотя согласно одному из принципов SOLID - всё правильно

Класс Parser - разбирает HTTP ответ

```
public class Parser {
    private Logger logger = new Logger();

    public User getUserFromJSON() {
        JsonElement jsonTree = new JsonParser().parse(new HTTPWorker().getResponseByRequest().toString());
        if(jsonTree.isJsonObject()){
            JsonElement results = jsonTree.getAsJsonObject().get("results");
            if(results.isJsonArray()){
                JsonElement name = getArrayObject(results,"name");
                JsonElement firstName = getValue(name, "first");
                JsonElement lastName = getValue(name, "last");

                JsonElement email = getArrayObject(results,"email");
                JsonElement phone = getArrayObject(results,"phone");
                JsonElement nationality = getArrayObject(results,"nat");

                JsonElement location = getArrayObject(results,"location");
                JsonElement state = getValue(location, "state");
                JsonElement city = getValue(location, "city");
                JsonElement street = getValue(location, "street");

                //System.out.println("||| " + firstName + lastName + email + phone + nationality + state + city + street);
                return new User(firstName.toString(), lastName.toString(), email.toString(), phone.toString(),
                                nationality.toString(), state.toString(), city.toString(), street.toString());
            }
        }
        logger.logJsonChanged();
        return null;
    }

    private JsonElement getArrayObject(JsonElement array, String objectName){
        return array.getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get(objectName);
    }

    private JsonElement getValue(JsonElement object, String objectName){
        if(object.isJsonObject()) {
            return object.getAsJsonObject().get(objectName);
        }
        logger.logJsonChanged();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Что меня смущает:
- его название. Возможно назвать более конкретно. Например, RandomUserParser
- return null; - хорошо ли так - IDEA предложила. Если нет - как избавится
- присутствует явные объект new Logger() - вводится зависимость. Как её избежать?

Класс Users - создаёт и отдаёт коллекцию пользователей

```
public class Users {
    private final int count = 110;
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    public void populate(){
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            users.add(new Parser().getUserFromJSON());
        }
    }

    public List<User> get(){
        return users;
    }
}
```

Что меня смущает
- нужен ли он вообще. Users перекликается с существующим User - не очень хорошо. Если не нужен, куда поместить его бизнес логику? В main? Но тогда загромоздится main.

Класс Main

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Users users = new Users();
            users.populate();
            for (User user : users.get()) {
                System.out.print("Имя: " + user.getFirstName().replace("\"", "") + "    " +
                        "Фамилия: " + user.getLastName().replace("\"", "") + "\n");
            }

            System.out.print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            int userNum = 10;
            System.out.print("Имя: " + users.get().get(10).getFirstName().replace("\"", "") + "\n" +
                             "Фамилия: " + users.get().get(userNum).getLastName().replace("\"", "") + "\n" +
                             "E-mail: " + users.get().get(userNum).getEmail().replace("\"", "") + "\n" +
                             "Телефон: " + users.get().get(userNum).getPhone().replace("\"", "") + "\n" +
                             "Национальность: " + users.get().get(userNum).getNationality().replace("\"", "") + "\n" +
                             "Место жительства: " +
                             "штат " + users.get().get(userNum).getState().replace("\"", "") + ", " +
                             "город " + users.get().get(userNum).getCity().replace("\"", "") + ", " +
                             "улица " + use

rs.get().get(userNum).getStreet().replace("\"", ""));
    }
}
```

---

UPD

Улучшил HttpClient - избавил его от зависимости - урла, теперь я его в конструктор перадаю

```
public class HttpClient {

    private String url = null;
    public HttpClient(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }

    public StringBuffer getResponse() {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            return response;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

улучшил Logger

```
public class Logger {

    private Logger(){}

    public static void logJsonChanged(){
        System.out.println("Не получилось обработать узел json дерева. Структура json у randomuser.me изменилась или другая причина");
    }
}
```

улучшил Users - убрал захардкоженный count, избавился от зависимости

```
public class Users {

    private int count;
    public Users(int count){
        this.count = count;
    }

    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    public void populate(){
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            users.add(new Parser().getUserFromJSON());
        }
    }

    public List<User> get(){
        return users;
    }
}
```

Изменённый Parser

```
public class Parser {
    public User getUserFromJSON() {
        StringBuffer httpResponse =  new HttpClient("https://randomuser.me/api/").getResponse();
        JsonElement jsonTree = new JsonParser().parse(httpResponse.toString());
        if(jsonTree.isJsonObject()){
            JsonElement results = jsonTree.getAsJsonObject().get("results");
            if(results.isJsonArray()){
                JsonElement name = getArrayObject(results,"name");
                JsonElement firstName = getValue(name, "first");
                JsonElement lastName = getValue(name, "last");

                JsonElement email = getArrayObject(results,"email");
                JsonElement phone = getArrayObject(results,"phone");
                JsonElement nationality = getArrayObject(results,"nat");

                JsonElement location = getArrayObject(results,"location");
                JsonElement state = getValue(location, "state");
                JsonElement city = getValue(location, "city");
                JsonElement street = getValue(location, "street");

                //System.out.println("||| " + firstName + lastName + email + phone + nationality + state + city + street);
                return new User(firstName.toString(), lastName.toString(), email.toString(), phone.toString(),
                                nationality.toString(), state.toString(), city.toString(), street.toString());
            }
        }
        Logger.logJsonChanged();
        return null;
    }

    private JsonElement getArrayObject(JsonElement array, String objectName){
        return array.getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get(objectName);
    }

    private JsonElement getValue(JsonElement object, String objectName){
        if(object.isJsonObject()) {
            return object.getAsJsonObject().get(objectName);
        }
        Logger.logJsonChanged();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Пару советов :
1) Посмотрите, что такое ломбок (https://projectlombok.org/features/all)
Он поможет вам избавиться от загромождения кода сеттерами, геттерами и конструкторами.
2) В классе логер сделайте приватный конструктор, а метод логгирования - статическим.
3) HttpClient - метод назовите getResponse , в него передавайте url в виде стринга, переменную url уберите из класса.

Да и в остальном - у вас классы не расширяемые и вся логика инкапсулирована в приватных полях, а методы не принимают никаких аргументов.

Что , если я захочу 5 юзеров получить ? Или поменять урл ?

Comment: Почему классы не расширяемые?

Answer (score 0):

Сделал небольшой рефакторинг Вашего кода.
Основные изменения:
1. Добавлены 2 интерфейса:
1.1 Parser
1.2 HttpClient
2. Изменил Ваши классы на их реализации.
3. Сделал получение списка как DAO, можно еще допилить.
В итоге получение списка стало легко заменяемым:

```
    UserDao users =
                    new UserDao(
                            new JsonParserImpl(
                                    new StringHttpClient("https://randomuser.me/api/")
                            )
                    );
```

Полный текст:

```
    import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
    import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    interface Parser<T> {
        T parse();
    }

    interface HttpClient<T> {
        T getData();
    }

    public class App {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            UserDao users =
                    new UserDao(
                            new JsonParserImpl(
                                    new StringHttpClient("https://randomuser.me/api/")
                            )
                    );
            users.populate();

            List<User> userList = users.getAll();

            for (User user : userList) {
                System.out.print("Имя: " + user.getFirstName().replace("\"", "") + "    " +
                        "Фамилия: " + user.getLastName().replace("\"", "") + "\n");
            }

            System.out.print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            int userNum = 10;

            User user = userList.get(userNum);

            System.out.print("Имя: " + user.getFirstName().replace("\"", "") + "\n" +
                    "Фамилия: " + user.getLastName().replace("\"", "") + "\n" +
                    "E-mail: " + user.getEmail().replace("\"", "") + "\n" +
                    "Телефон: " + user.getPhone().replace("\"", "") + "\n" +
                    "Национальность: " + user.getNationality().replace("\"", "") + "\n" +
                    "Место жительства: " +
                    "штат " + user.getState().replace("\"", "") + ", " +
                    "город " + user.getCity().replace("\"", "") + ", " +
                    "улица " + user.getStreet().replace("\"", ""));
        }
    }

    class User {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String email;
        private String phone;
        private String nationality;
        private String state;
        private String city;
        private String street;

        public User(String firstName,
                    String lastName,
                    String email,
                    String phone,
                    String nationality,
                    String state,
                    String city,
                    String street) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.email = email;
            this.phone = phone;
            this.nationality = nationality;
            this.state = state;
            this.city = city;
            this.street = street;

        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public String getPhone() {
            return phone;
        }

        public String getNationality() {
            return nationality;
        }

        public String getState() {
            return state;
        }

        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        public String getStreet() {
            return street;
        }
    }

    class StringHttpClient implements HttpClient<String> {

        private String url;

        public StringHttpClient(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        public String getData() {
            try {
                URL obj = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                return response.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    class JsonParserImpl implements Parser<User> {

        private HttpClient httpClient;

        public JsonParserImpl(HttpClient httpClient) {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public User parse() {
            JsonElement jsonTree = new JsonParser().parse(httpClient.getData().toString());
            if (jsonTree.isJsonObject()) {
                JsonElement results = jsonTree.getAsJsonObject().get("results");
                if (results.isJsonArray()) {
                    JsonElement name = getArrayObject(results, "name");
                    JsonElement firstName = getValue(name, "first");
                    JsonElement lastName = getValue(name, "last");

                    JsonElement email = getArrayObject(results, "email");
                    JsonElement phone = getArrayObject(results, "phone");
                    JsonElement nationality = getArrayObject(results, "nat");

                    JsonElement location = getArrayObject(results, "location");
                    JsonElement state = getValue(location, "state");
                    JsonElement city = getValue(location, "city");
                    JsonElement street = getValue(location, "street");

                    //System.out.println("||| " + firstName + lastName + email + phone + nationality + state + city + street);
                    return new User(firstName.toString(), lastName.toString(), email.toString(), phone.toString(),
                            nationality.toString(), state.toString(), city.toString(), street.toString());
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private JsonElement getArrayObject(JsonElement array, String objectName) {
            return array.getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get(objectName);
        }

        private JsonElement getValue(JsonElement object, String objectName) {
            if (object.isJsonObject()) {
                return object.getAsJsonObject().get(objectName);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    class UserDao {
        private final int count = 110;

        private Parser<User> parser;

        private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

        public UserDao(Parser<User> parser) {
            this.parser = parser;
        }

        public void populate() {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                users.add(parser.parse());
            }
        }

        public List<User> getAll() {
            return users;
        }
    }
```